# Pip help install

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install tensorflow on ubuntu from: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#virtualenv_installation
But when I get to the step: `pip install --upgrade $ TF_BINARY_URL`
I get this error:

> `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install").`

Any help please

Comment: What is the output of  `echo $TF_BINARY_URL` in your terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the environment variable `$TF_BINARY_URL` is not set. you must export it first, like described in the docs you provided.

> ```
> # Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
> (tensorflow)$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
> ```

(or any other url specific to arch/platform)